# Mobile Number from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud

Tags: mobileconnect

Problem Statement:

1. Sales Cloud is integrated with Marketing Cloud
2. The mobile number in Account, if 10 digits, is stored as (123)456-7890 in both Sales and Marketing Clouds
3. In SFMC, we sync Accounts in a DE which also stores the number in the above format.
4. Next we have a journey from which we send SMS and in this SMS we have some personalization such as Account First Name
5. In MobileConnect the Mobile number is stored as 1234567890. We take this mobile number and then query the Account DE but the query fails because in the Account DE, the mobile number was stored as (123)456-7890
6. We thought of formatting the mobile number at the time of fetching it from Sync DE into another DE but SQL in SFMC does not support replace function.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Replace may not be supported however as the length is constant you could  use LEFT and RIGHT functions to create the required format by breaking the number into smaller chunks then combining them back together with the "(" and ")" characters.